# Why is generic EventHandler<TArgs> so under-used?

Tags: c#, events, generics, delegates

.NET 2.0 added the `EventHandler<TArgs>` generic delegate type to simplify the process of writing custom events; instead of having to define an `EventArgs` class and its corresponding delegate (e.g. `MyEventArgs` and `MyEventHandler`), you need only write the args class.

Bearing that in mind, why does this delegate type appear almost nowhere in the .NET Framework? I know that most of the core APIs were developed before generics were introduced, but even in new parts of the framework like WPF, they have opted for explicitly defining delegate types; e.g. `RoutedEventHandler` instead of `EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>`.

Is there something inherently wrong with the generic event handler delegate? I often make use of it and I worry that my code appears very out of place when compared to built-in classes.

Comment: I suspect the introduction of `EventHandler<T>` was just bad timing. By the time it was introduced, the other pattern (explicitly named delegates) was firmly established and starting a shift towards the generic delegate type could have been seen as making an even bigger mess (by leading to confused programmers asking, _"What was that delegate called again? `FooEventHandler` or `EventHandler<Foo>`?"_) -- Which makes me curious if the shift towards `IEvent<T>` (introduced by F# and the Rx framework) will work.

Comment: WPF was started in July of 2003, well before generics were available.  Same goes for Windows Forms of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just an accident of history. If we had generics in .NET 1 most of the other delegates wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's anything wrong with it. It *is* used in some places of the framework... in the [`GeoCoordinateWatcher.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.positionchanged.aspx) event, just as a random example.

It's a little clumsier to see in code than a specific type name like `RoutedEventHandler` - and as you're going to use `RoutedEventHandler` a *lot* in WPF/Silverlight, maybe that's why MS decided to give it its own type.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be that when you're writing framework level code you tend to be more explicit. When you write toolkit and application level code not so.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just my personal oppinion, but it seems (oviously) reasonable for me;
If we take a close look of how you work using .net and v studio, it appears that generic type notation seems to leak some "beauty".

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("hello world");
```

While the code above is pretty simple, straight forward and well supported by intelli sense the EventHandler "look and feel" doesnt appear that clear. The default intelli support will suggest just the EventHandler, not its generic. Further the notation just looks awfull:

```
private event EventHandler<MyClass> SomeEvent;
private event EventHandler<AnotehrClass> OtherEvent;
privete event EventHandler<MoreClass> MoreEvents;
```

While overviewing the code you will read "EventHandler" every time and your mind might connect those delegates, beacuse you are used to identify the relationship of types by their names.
On the other side there might also be a less isoterical and more technical/logical explanation:
First of all you always get a sender object in the handling method. While this seems usefull at first glance - it is barley ever used.
Further your arguments have to derive from EventArgs which might be annoying or sometimes even just immposible due to the usage of existing components.
Other than the the typical generics (e.g. IList/List) you leak the possibility to use a more abstract type (like an interface) or just a simple type (like a double).
Last but no least there are those notation rules/suggestions introduced by microsoft - for your example about the routed event the rule might say that its type is "marked" as beeing routed by having its name stared with the word "Routed". While the naming for the event by itself says the the name startes with a "Preview".
 As i mentioned: this is just my opinion so dont blame me ;)

Comment: The `sender` parameter most definitely has its uses. It comes into its own whenever you have the same handler bound to events on multiple objects. While it's not useful all the time, people who use your code expect it to be available. As for the use of descendants of `EventArgs`, I personally think that promotes the idea of putting a gate between your code and the user's - ensuring you never accidentally give them a mutable object that you don't want them to modify, etc. Your remarks regarding naming are definitely valid, though. Makes me wish C# had `typedef`...